# Real Analysis- Uniform convergence of Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

[image]

I am stuck in this question (image link given above). I have solved the first part that fn(x) converges to a continuous function but I am not getting any idea to solve the 2nd part to prove fn(x) doesn't converge uniformly. Please help me...
I will post my work proving the first part in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon =1/2$ , take $x_n=\frac 2{2n+1}$

Then show  $1/(n+1) \le x_n \le 1/n$

Clearly $|f_n(x_n)|=1 \gt \epsilon$

Can you conclude ?